# Establish PDO MySQL connection without password (password set in [client] section in MySQL config)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What I'm trying to achieve is allow connection to MySQL server without defining password in PDO connection, instead of it I would like to define it in MySQL configuration.

I already created file /etc/mysql/conf.d/nopass.cnf with content:

```
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = someuser
password = somepass
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

When connecting from shell it works as expected:

```
$ mysql -u someuser
mysql>
```

However, I'm not able to connect via PHP:

```
new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;charset=utf8;dbname=somedb', 'someuser');
new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;charset=utf8;dbname=somedb', 'someuser', null);
new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;charset=utf8;dbname=somedb', 'someuser', );
```

In each case I receive error

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

It works if I set correct password

```
new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;charset=utf8;dbname=somedb', 'someuser', 'somepassword');
```

Is it possible to make this work?

Comment: So, you have a password protected database and a user with an assigned password and want to connect without a password? *That does not make sense.*

Comment: @JayBlanchard Like I wrote, it works if I connect directly from command line without password ($ mysql -u someuser). I'm trying to achieve same thing with PDO.

Comment: Then you need a user without a password. BTW, that just sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Maybe explain *why* it works by the command line, but not by PHP. How is one method of connecting to the database differing from the other.

Comment: Isn't that obvious @Mike?

Comment: @schtr4jh The reason it works from the command line is because MySQL checks the configuration and utilizes the password there. Connecting remotely (i.e. not from the command line) doesn't bring the configuration file into play, so MySQL has no idea what the requesting user's password is.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I was going to guess it was because by the command line the user is not selecting a database for use while in PHP they are.

Comment: Actually, you can establish PDO connection without dbname=sth parameter and then manually select / switch between databases.
@JayBlanchard This actually makes sense, otherwise all applications on webserver could instantiate connection with credentials defined in configuration - and you already have access to those files if you're connected via ssh / in command line.
Thanks guys, I will need to look for another solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as my testing has gone, PDO requires that something is provided in the password field so no matter what config setup you're using it will try to use its own syntax. If there is no password, then the password field should be set to an empty string i.e. `''` and it submits that empty string as your password. The short answer is, AFAIK it's not possible to do what you're trying.

If your primary concern is having a password revealed due to someone finding a way to snoop around your PHP files, having it placed in a client config is a good method to try to circumvent that but there are native PHP methods that can also hide the sensitive information from potential security breaches stemming from leaked PHP file contents.

I answered a similar question not too long ago that talks about the three main recommendations I'd make regarding PHP security for SQL passwords here: [Set up PDO connection without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946544/set-up-pdo-connection-without-password/65516560#65516560) which mostly includes moving the php script outside your webdata directory as well as protecting php files from direct access even if accessed by using redirects to hide their existence and having code that returns a 404 error if the files themselves are directly accessed. Also I'd suggest making PHP-exclusive accounts that have very limited access scopes so in case someone does find a way to inject sql, they won't be able to do or see much. For examples of what I'm talking about, feel free to follow the link to read up.