# Cache dynamic JavaScript generated by PHP

Tags: php, caching, cross-browser, minify

I use [JShrink](https://github.com/tedivm/JShrink) with a custom function to combine 8 uncompressed JavaScript files to a single compressed (minified) one, like this:

```
<?php
// Filename: js.php 
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
require_once '../JShrink.php';

function concatenateFiles($files)
{
    $buffer = '';

    foreach($files as $file) {
        $buffer .= file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/' . $file);
    }

    return $buffer;
}

$js = concatenateFiles([
  'core.min.js', 
  'promise.js', 
  'welcome.js',
  'imagesloaded.js',
  'cropper.js',
  'translate.js',
  'custom.js',
  'masonry.js',
]);

$output = \JShrink\Minifier::minify($js);
echo $output;
```

Then I call this php file in my index page footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<? echo $url ?>/js/js.php"></script>
```

It is not being cached.

I modify my JS codes daily and I don't like to keep combining them manually, but also I need a way to get the echoed JS code cached, only that code and not all php files on the server.

How can I do this, and how would the cache purge process be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you need to use a header("...") with proper expiration. In practice, that's not working properly. You can spend your life googling for proper examples of "Cache-Control" and "Expires:" and none of what you find will work. So I suggest you to read this:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching

ETags are the modern solution to tell the browser when your resource has changed - or not.

Comment: You made my day man, thanks. I followed your note and found this great answer, I hope it helps someone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197479/how-to-use-etags-in-a-php-file

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Have a nice optimized data transfer!

Answer (score 0):

If the cache file doesnt exist or if any of the file modification timestamps is later then the cache, render it, then safe it to the cache, then echo the cache or the rendered result.