# Does the ETag header make the Cache-Control header obsolete? How to make sure Cache-Control is not harmful then?

Tags: http, caching, http-headers, cache-control, etag

Definition of ETag header (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag):

> The ETag HTTP response header is an identifier for a specific version
>   of a resource. It allows caches to be more efficient, and saves
>   bandwidth, as a web server does not need to send a full response if
>   the content has not changed. On the other side, if the content has
>   changed, etags are useful to help prevent simultaneous updates of a
>   resource from overwriting each other ("mid-air collisions").

Definition of Cache-Control header (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control):

> The Cache-Control general-header field is used to specify directives
>   for caching mechanisms in both requests and responses.

So the ETag header tells the browser for a resource to send a single HTTP request to the server and ask if the file hash has changed. If yes, download a new one. Great. So if the ETag header is set why should I need Cache-Control any more (beside of the Expires header which may help to avoid this single request)?

So if I have to set the Cache-Control header anyway it can only be harmful right? I think the most appropriate value would be:

```
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
```

But I am not sure if this triggers unecessary additional actions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After some research, I found a great tutorial on *Medium* by Alex Barashkov: ["Best practices for cache control settings for your website"](https://medium.com/pixelpoint/best-practices-for-cache-control-settings-for-your-website-ff262b38c5a2).

Alex writes:

> I recommend you apply `Cache-Control: no-cache` to html files. Applying
>   “no-cache” does not mean that there is no cache at all, it simply
>   tells the browser to validate resources on the server before use it
>   from the cache. That’s why we need to use it with Etag, so browsers
>   will send a simple request and load the extra 80 bytes to verify the
>   state of the file.

Answer (score 17):

Presence of `ETag` header does not tell the browser to do anything. Browser decides what to do based on the `Cache-Control` header it receives in the request and cached response. If it decides that resource is stale or needs to be re-validated, then it can use the `ETag` value to create a conditional request to the server and either get a new resource (status code 200), or a notification that things have not changed (status code 304)

Both headers are necessary for your cache to work optimally.

Comment: "Leaving out the Cache-Control response header does not disable HTTP caching" https://web.dev/http-cache/#cache-control