# is it possible to cache a php page that have "GET" variables with 'Cache-Control: public, max-age=n' header?

Tags: php, apache2

i have this php page that looks like this:

`/get_data.php?forid=123&pdid=456&exclude_ids=`

it's accessed publicly and return the same content when provided with the same variables -"GET" variables that are included in the link- ,and i can't seem to have the browser cache the page so it won't bother the server every time the page is needed!

I've tried and added this line to the head of get_data.php but no luck 

`header('Cache-Control: public, max-age=7200');`

this is the php file code:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Cache-Control: public, max-age=7200');

require('config.php');
$link_database = new mysqli($host,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$database);
...
?>
```

accessed like this in javascript:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/get_data.php?forid="+forid+"&pdid="+pdid+"&exclude_ids="+existing_ids.join(","), true);
```

tested with firefox i get this raw response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 15 Jun 2019 16:04:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
Cache-Control: public, max-age=7200
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=91
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
```

is what i'm trying to do even a possibility?
if it is, how can i?

ps: the php code execute a simple sql, and a pure php cache system will not give any advantages(i think!).

Comment: *"is it possible to cache a php page that have “GET” variables?"* i think you are looking for [HTTP ETag headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use etags in a PHP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197479/how-to-use-etags-in-a-php-file), offcource you would have the change/program a algorithm that knows when a variable has changed by quering a database.

Comment: I've added an etag header, it seem to be working but who is responsible for the '304 not modified' response is it the client or the server, if it's the server that still isn't what i was hoping for!

Comment: i have not added a code to check for IF_NONE_MATCH then return a '304 Not Modified' response, to test i've set max-age=10, and in firefox shows '304 Not Modified' response, until more then 10 seconds pass then i get a 200 response code, does that mean header('Cache-Control: public, max-age=10') didn't work before because it needed etag header?

Comment: @abdeba coould you please mark my answer as the answer if it accompish your requirement